# Picks on latency graph of a Flink/Kafka application

Tags: twitter, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a application that receives tweets from a Kafka topic, have a window of one second, and then save these tweets on Cassandra by a AsyncIO operation that allows to open maximum of 100 threads(last parameter of AsyncIO operator) without doing any pre-processing on the data: just save tweet by tweet with a timestamp of when it was saved.

Then, I have stressed the Flink application sending 3 million tweets and did a graph in Grafana that shows how many tweets are being saved on the database, but this graph show some picks, is not a continuous line, and I can't understand why.

So you can see that in an interval of one minute it saves 7k then goes to 5k and then to 2k for example. How can I find out why?

[image]

Comment: Why not use Kafka Connect instead of AsyncIO?

Comment: because I did that way, I didn't know Kafka connect, will search more about it. Also, in the future, I will use flink in order to do some operation on the data before saving on the database. Do you have any idea of why this behaviour?

Comment: Are you using Event Time or Processing Time semantics?

Comment: I do not know... Also, unclear if you are live-streaming tweets or bulk-loading. Also, Kafka producer, by default, will batch events together, so you can play with batch or request sizes. RE: Connect, you can still use Flink from Kafka->Kafka, then Kafka Connect from there into a database

Comment: Event time semantics on live-streamming tweets. The batch events on Kafka producer I just figure it out some hours ago, it's a good idea to play with it. I will try.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to write to cassandra, I'd use the [connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/cassandra.html#cassandra-sinks). Implementing something like exactly-once manually correctly is very hard if not close to impossible.

Second, AsyncIO is not starting 100 threads. In fact, it's not starting any threads for users. You need to start them yourself through any means. Usually, it's using the callback mechanism of the external systems where the libraries have their own connection pool.

If you are making synchronize calls, you need to manage your own thread pool. I recommend using 
`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` and submitting your async tasks to it. AsyncIO will only help to merge the async results back into a synchronous stream.

Third, 100 threads might be quite a lot, depending on your setup. Also note that if you use Flink's scale-up (using more than one slot per taskmanager) would multiply the used threads.